# C++ my copy constructor fails to move the memory to a new area

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, copy-constructor

So I've recently started to work on getting my own vector class working and I'm a little bit stuck on my copy constructor. I'm obviously rather new to c++ and was hoping the good guys at stack overflow could help me out a bit. So I got this copy constructor which copies the actual ptr being used, the end index of the ptr (the elements the user can use) and the actual capacity/reserved memory the ptr has, plus the size of the used memory.

```
    vector(const vector &other) : storage(other.storage), capacity(other.capacity), 
        endIndex(other.endIndex), m_size(other.m_size)
    {
        T* storage = new T[capacity];
        memcpy(storage, other.storage, sizeof(T) * capacity);
    }
```

The issue is that while it seemingly copies the information successfully, if one of the objects run out of scope, the information, or at least some of it gets deleted. If I also do a push_back on one of the vector objects, it happens on both of them. So it's fairly safe to say that they share address for their ptr. For example if I run this code in my main function

```
int main()
{

    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(55);
    vec.push_back(500);
    vector<int> vec1 = vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << vec1[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I will get this error message

```
5
55
500
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm assuming this is because the ptr gets deleted while going through the loop and it in turn crashes the program in a nice fashion. Another example of the push_back is

```
int main()
{

    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(55);
    vec.push_back(500);
    vector<int> vec1 = vec;
    vec.push_back(55);

    for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size() + 1; i++)
    {
        std::cout << vec1[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Where you can obviously see that i actually push_back on the original vector object and not the new one, i even have to increase the for-loops scope to be able to see the object on the new vector, hinting at the size integer in the new object is unchanged from before. Output of this code is:

```
5
55
500
55
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't expect anyone to take time out of their day to debug my code, I don't want that. I'm merely asking for a pair of professional eyes to glance over it and help a newbie out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is with `T* storage = new T[capacity];` in the copy-constructor. Think about what it does. And think about what the initializer `storage(other.storage)` does.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your program, and look exactly at the members of both vectors, maybe that will give you an idea what's wrong.

Comment: FYI implementing a vector in a standard conform way without undefined behavior is still a problem: [implementing a std::vector like container without undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996590) and [P0593R6
Implicit creation of objects for low-level object manipulation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html). Normally it will work because for the mayor compilers it is know how they will work in these particular situations. But it is an important information to be aware of.

Comment: `memcpy` will only work for trivial copy able object. `int` would be fine, you can't use your implementation with any object that is not trivial copy able.

Comment: `memcpy` -- No.  Use `std::copy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

The first and foremost one is this:

`T* storage = new T[capacity];`

That `storage` is **not** the same as the member variable `storage`.  It is a local variable that just happens to have the same name.  Once the copy constructor is complete, you haven't done anything except leak memory.

---

In addition, you have this:

`vector(const vector &other) : storage(other.storage),`

This assigns the pointer `other.storage` to `this`.  This is actually where the double-free comes from.  You are doing a shallow copy, thus when `this` and `other` are destroyed, the same pointer value will be used in the call to `delete []` in the destructor.

---

The third issue is this:

`memcpy(storage, other.storage, sizeof(T) * capacity);`

This will not work for types that are not trivially-copyable.  Let's say you fix all the issues except this one.  This code will fail miserably:

`vector<std::string> s;`

and the reason is that you can't use `memcpy` to copy `std::string` objects, since `std::string` is not trivially-copyable.

The fix is to use `std::copy`, not `memcpy`, since `std::copy` is (should be) smart enough to either do a `memcpy` for trivially-copyable types, or a plain loop for non trivially-copyable types.

---

The last issue is your naming of the class `vector`.  Note that there already is a `std::vector` in C++.  Either change the name to something else, or place your class in its own namespace so that a name clash will not occur if you happen to `#include <vector>` somewhere.

Putting that all together, you will have this (not compiled, forgive any syntax errors):

---

```
#include <algorithm>

namespace myVector
{
    template <typename T>
    class vector
    {
       private:
            // your member variables
       public:
         //... 
         vector(const vector &other) : capacity(other.capacity), 
                endIndex(other.endIndex), m_size(other.m_size)
        {
          storage = new T[capacity]();
          std::copy(other.storage, other.storage + other.m_size, storage);
        }

        vector& operator=(const vector& other) 
        {
            // see later
        }

        ~vector()
        {
           delete [] storage;
        } 
      //...
  };
}
```

Then the `main` could be this:

```
#include <myvector>

int main()
{
    myVector::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(55);
    vec.push_back(500);
    myVector::vector<int> vec1 = vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << vec1[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Once this is all done and corrected, to complete the rule of 3, the assignment operator can be simply this:

```
vector& operator=(const vector& other)
{
   if ( &other != this )
   { 
       vector temp(other);
       std::swap(temp.capacity, capacity);
       std::swap(temp.m_size, m_size);
       std::swap(temp.endIndex, endIndex);
       std::swap(temp.storage, storage);
   } 
   return *this;
}
```

The above is using the [copy/swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple, but hard to see in your own code since you know what you want it to do. You could track it down by stepping through in a debugger and examining the value *and address* of `storage` scrupulously on every line.

Seriously, try doing that first.

---

OK, so here is it:

```
vector(const vector &other)
: storage(other.storage)    // 1. copy the pointer, so this->storage is shared
, capacity(other.capacity)
, endIndex(other.endIndex)
, m_size(other.m_size)
{
    // 2. declare a local variable called storage which shadows this->storage
    T* storage = new T[capacity];
    memcpy(storage, other.storage, sizeof(T) * capacity);
}
```

---

You *do not want* the storage to be shared, so you should never initialize `storage(other.storage)`. There is literally no reason to do this in your code. If you just initialize it to `nullptr` you would have realized very quickly that the local variable in the constructor body was wrong.

Simply removing the `T*` from `T* storage = ...` will fix your immediate problem. All the other suggestions about using `std::copy` instead of `memcpy`, and how better to structure your code are good ones, and you should do those too.