# How is std::vector able to be constexpr without constexpr std::uninitialized_copy?

Tags: c++, initialization, std, constexpr

I am implementing my own container and I was trying to make it as much constexpr friendly as possible.

In the process I found out that `std::uninitialized_copy` is not constexpr and therefore I can't implement copy assignment using the standard algorithms.

However, `std::vector` *is* constexpr friendly:

```
constexpr auto f() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    return v.size();
}

static_assert(f() == 3);
```

I can't achieve this when I replace `std::vector` by my own container.
I get the error:

```
... error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, ...
```

I wonder how the standard library (e.g. stdlib) can implement that.
Does it use a secret implementation of `uninitialized_copy` that is constexpr?
Is a constexpr uninitalized_copy implementable at all?

I guess the challenge is to have `constexpr addressof` and `constexpr construct_at`.
Is there an implementation that I can fallback into?

Comment: FWIW, if you are trying to implement your own vector, `vector` itself skirts the rules of C++.  For instance it holds a pointer to unallocated storage, so the underlying pointer arithmetic is UB.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996590/implementing-a-stdvector-like-container-without-undefined-behavior

Comment: @NathanOliver Although I don't understand why exactly arithmetic on unallocated storage is UB, I know that standard library implementations can violate c++ rules. I don't understand if there is a connection between the two problems either.

Comment: @NathanOliver, does it imply that `boost::container::vector` uses UB?

Comment: Yes, technically they do but they work because the UB is sensible.  My point is vector the implementation of vector can do things you cant.  For instance they could use a compiler  intrinsic built in function to do the compile time allocation so that it can be constexpr when the "standard way" isn't.

Comment: When you know exactly how the compiler will interpret a piece of code and how that will run on the target hardware, via years of experience and careful testing, you can do some pretty amazing, totally illegal stuff.

Comment: @NathanOliver, it makes sense. I guess I am adopting the Boost philosophy then, implementing things in a sensible way, even if it is technically UB. I would love to know all the times I am recoursing to UB in my library (https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi) though.

Comment: @NathanOliver, as a **partial** solution and to avoid implementing an incorrect unintialized_copy, what I am doing at the moment is falling back to `std::copy` (which is constexp)` when I can `if(std::is_constant_evaluated() && std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<ValueType>) {return std::copy(first, last, d_first);} else {return std::uninitialized_copy(first, last, d_first);}`

Comment: Since C++20, most (all?) of the constructors and copy-assignment operators of `std::vector` are `constexpr`.    They are not required to call `std::initialized_copy()` nor are they required to use standard algorithms.    This leaves a fair amount of freedom for implementers (say, to use "compiler magic", or to use "UB that behaves sensibly even though it is UB").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::vector` doesn't use `std::uninitialized_copy`. It calls `std::allocator_traits::construct` to perform copy construction. The latter defaults to calling `std::construct_at`, which is handled specially during constant evaluation ([[expr.const]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6.sentence-2)).

In practice, compilers treats `std::construct_at` specially, so that it can use placement new during constant evaluation.

- MSVC uses a secret attribute to define the placement `operator new` and to call it inside `std::construct_at`. (Well, [it's not *that* secret](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10259132).)
- Clang permits placement new during constant evaluation when the enclosing function is within namespace `std`.
- GCC and EDG permit placement new when the enclosing function template is named `std::construct_at`.

Comment: Great answer. So, `construct_at` (or at least `std`) is really magic then. Good to know. I guess I can reimplement `uninitialized_copy` inside my library using `construct_at`. Would I be doing something illegal then? It seems I am getting away with it.

Comment: @alfC `std::construct_at` is permitted in a constant expression only if the storage was allocated by `std::allocator`. Any place where this `uninitialized_copy` could be used in a constant expression could just as well use `std::allocator::construct`. It may give the false impression that your function is _generally_ usable in constant expressions, not only in this special case. Aside from that I think it is valid.

Comment: @user17732522, thanks for the tip. At the time I am "running" `x::uninitialized_copy` I can't know if `std::allocator` was used. Also there is an information mismatch, `std::allocator::construct` takes an instance of the allocator as argument, so it is more fit to implement what I call `x::alloc_uninitialized_copy`.

Comment: @alfC If you want your vector implementation to be as close as possible to the standard's specification, then it is also necessary that you use `allocator_traits::construct`, because a user would be permitted to customize its behavior and the specification requires vector to support this customization.

Comment: @user17732522, that is interesting, this means that it would be incorrect (incomplete) to even call `std::uninitialized_copy`? Fortunately, I am allowing this customization point accidentally because I first tried using a hand-rolled `x::alloc_uninitialized_copy` function. https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/include/multi/detail/adl.hpp?ref_type=heads#L382-396

Comment: @alfC For full standard-conformance you can call `std::uninitialized_copy` only if the allocator is `std::allocator` and if not in a constant expression. If the element type is then additionally trivially-copyable it can be further reduced to a memcpy. I am pretty sure I saw special cases like that for optimization in C++ standard library implementations before.

Comment: @user17732522, ah, I see. In that case it is std::vector, which will call `std::uninitialized_copy` iff `std::allocator` is the Allocator. The question is why would it, since it is not constexpr and/or it has to call a more generic `alloc_uninitialized_copy` anyway to honor the customization point.

Comment: @alfC E.g. libstdc++ uses `__uninitialized_copy_n_a` from the constructor, specializing it for `std::allocator` and distinguishing on constant expression context, using `std::uninitialized_copy` outside of it, see https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h#L373. Then eventually through https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_uninitialized.h#L147 it gets rid of the placement-new, using `std::copy` instead, for types that (on GCC) don't require it and then reduces to `memmove` if the types allow it.