# equivalent implementation of C++20 variadic capture

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic

Out of pure curiosity, while watching [C++ weekly ep 171](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwYYc5dpvqk) I was wondering how variadic capture could be implemented, so I merely "asked" cppinsight. Here is the input snippet:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <typename C, typename... A>
auto bind_values(C callable, A... args) {
    return [callable = std::move(callable), ... my_param = std::move(args)]() {
        return callable(my_param...);
    };
}

int add(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }

int main() {
    const auto bound = bind_values(add, 1, 2);
    return bound();
}
```

And the output of [cppinsight](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHV0aWxpdHk+Cgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTx0eXBlbmFtZSBDLHR5cGVuYW1lIC4uLiBBPgphdXRvIGJpbmRfdmFsdWVzKEMgY2FsbGFibGUsQS4uLiBhcmdzKQp7CiAgICByZXR1cm4gW2NhbGxhYmxlPXN0ZDo6bW92ZShjYWxsYWJsZSksLi4ubXlfcGFyYW09c3RkOjptb3ZlKGFyZ3MpXSgpewogICAgICAgIHJldHVybiBjYWxsYWJsZShteV9wYXJhbS4uLik7CiAgICB9Owp9CgppbnQgYWRkIChpbnQgbGhzLGludCByaHMpCnsKICAgIHJldHVybiBsaHMrcmhzOwp9CgppbnQgbWFpbigpCnsKICAgIGNvbnN0IGF1dG8gYm91bmQgPSBiaW5kX3ZhbHVlcyhhZGQsMSwyKTsKICAgIHJldHVybiBib3VuZCgpOwp9&insightsOptions=cpp20&std=cpp20&rev=1.0) (only the relevant part):

```cpp
  class __lambda_6_12
  {
    public: 
    inline auto operator()() const
    {
      return callable(my_param... );
    }
    
    private: 
    auto callable;
    auto... my_param;
    
    public:
    __lambda_6_12(auto _callable, auto const &... _my_param)
    : callable{_callable}
    , my_param{_my_param...}
    {}
    
  } __lambda_6_12{std::move(callable), std::move(args)};
```

I was surprised to see member variables declared with `auto` and even `auto...` and expected `tuple` instead (for instance).
Is it merely that cppinsight don't necessarily produced valid cpp code (but only a pseudo code) or is it real C++? I would be inclined to believe the first solution, as trying to compile the cppinsight code fails and I can't see how it could work anyway.

My version would more look like this:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
template <typename C, typename... A>
class __lambda_6_12 {
   public:
    inline auto operator()() const { return callable(my_param...); }

   private:
    C callable;
    std::tuple<A...> my_param;

   public:
    __lambda_6_12(C _callable, A const &..._my_param)
        : callable{_callable}, my_param{_my_param...} {}
};
```

Which seems to better suit the compiler.
(note my operator() above is wrong, the tuple should be expanded again into a pack, and the pack passed to callable)

Comment: strictly speaking `__lambda_6_12` would render it UB already. User code != code by the implementation

Comment: Given that a tuple is logically equivalent to the tuple members, since it has nothing else, both approaches are logically equivalent, and this is purely the compiler's choice. There is no practical difference, whatsoever. It's actually not even a compiler's choice. The suffering C++ compiler will use whatever internal mechanism is the most convenient for it, to implement variadic capture.

Comment: Implementation is allowed to make use of non-standard support as long as it doesn't alter the observed behavior. [It is not possible to implement std::vector without non-standard support of the compilers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996590/implementing-a-stdvector-like-container-without-undefined-behavior)