# Using unions with arrays of non-trivial types

Tags: c++, arrays, unions

If I have a union that contains an array of a non-trivial type (for example `std::string`)

```
using namespace std;

struct MyUnion {
    union {
        char c;
        string s[5];
    };
    MyUnion() {}
    ~MyUnion() {}
};
```

Is it legal (according to the C++ standard) to only initialize a part of this array and use it?

```
MyUnion mu;

// construct 2 strings using placement new
new (&mu.s[0]) string();
new (&mu.s[1]) string();

// do something with the strings
do_something(mu.s[0]);
do_something(mu.s[1]);

// destruct 2 strings
mu.s[0].~string();
mu.s[1].~string();
```

For some reason this question has been marked as a duplicate but this question is specifically about **arrays** and only initializing parts of the array. The proposed duplicates do not answer this question.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to correctly implement something like `inplace_vector`. `std::variant` does not help me here.

Comment: What's `inplace_vector`?

Comment: `inplace_vector`is a [proposed new data type](https://wg21.link/p0843) that can store up to N elements in-place.

Comment: On second thought, what does any of this have to do with unions? It's just about initializing part of the array.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996590/implementing-a-stdvector-like-container-without-undefined-behavior.

Comment: @PasserBy the union is needed to prevent the default constructor from running on all array elements, so that you can store types without a default constructor.

Comment: You could've described the problem with much more clarity. The closure was (IMO) a mistake but it's easy to be misled by the way you wrote.

Comment: @PasserBy `inplace_vector` is different from `std::vector` since it stores the elements in-place. That's why it needs a union (or something like `std::aligned_storage` which is now deprecated).

Comment: @PasserBy feel free to improve the wording of the question.

Comment: Looks reasonably legal to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it legal (according to the C++ standard) to only initialize a part of this array and use it?

Yes, but with some hassle.

```
MyUnion mu;
new (&mu.s[1]) string(); // #1
```

Pointer arithmetic is only legal on array objects, and there is no array object at #1. Consequently, `mu.s[1]` is by itself undefined behaviour.

Prior to C++20, there's no way to create the array `mu.s` without also creating all `string` subobjects (and calling their constructors).

With C++20, we can do

```
MyUnion mu;
new (&mu.s) char[sizeof(mu.s)]; // #2
new (&mu.s[1]) string();
```

Creating a `char` array is one of the operations specified to implicitly create objects. After #2, an array of `string` is implicitly created (without creating `string` subobjects), thus making `mu.s[1]` legal.

With C++23, the preferred solution is

```
MyUnion mu;
std::start_lifetime_as<decltype(MyUnion::s)>(&mu.s);
new (&mu.s[1]) string();
```

Comment: I'm starting to wonder whether it is even possible to implement `inplace_vector` in a standard-compliant way with older versions of C++. If you use a byte array as storage you need `std::launder` which is only available in C++17 and if you use a union you need C++20.

Comment: @eyelash It's impossible to implement `std::vector` and `inplace_vector` prior C++20. `std::launder` doesn't help with object lifetimes, so C++17 has the same problems. That said, I've yet to see a compiler exploit UB from pointer arithmetic on non-existent arrays and I'm skeptical they ever will: too much code relies on that.

Comment: I just realized that instead of putting the array inside the union, I could just create an array of `MyUnion`s. I can't implement the `data()` method but I can implement a custom iterator which should be enough for my use case.